# Switching from layout view to data/map view in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, import, layouts, mxd

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.7

I imported a map document created in ArcGIS Desktop into Pro. It opened up in Layout view, and I don't know how to switch to the Map view, which was easy to do in ArcMap by clicking the tab below the layout frame. All I see is the option to activate the map frame, but this doesn't actually switch to the map view. Likewise, when I create a new map in ArcGIS Pro it opens in Map view, and I would like to be able to switch the layout view.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try importing your MXD into a new project as a test.

Then go to your Catalog pane and look under the Layouts node.  If there is a layout listed there which does not appear as a view in the project then double-click it to open it.

Then look under the Maps node.  If there is a map listed there which does not appear as a view in the project then double-click it to open it.

You should now have both the Data and Layout views from your MXD open as map and layout views in your ArcGIS Pro project, and be able to switch between them using their tabs.

---

[You commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385299/switching-from-layout-view-to-data-map-view-in-arcgis-pro/385300?noredirect=1#comment631462_385300) that it:

> Opened into 'map view' when [you] double clicked 'Layers' in the Maps node.

That makes sense because your MXD by default would have had a data frame named "Layers", and the process of importing the MXD creates a map named "Layers" from that, which appears under the Maps node in the Catalog pane, but is not automatically opened in a map view.

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS Pro doesn't have the map/layout view switching paradigm, because you can open multiple views at the same time (for instance, side by side) if you want.

When you import an MXD both the layout and any maps inside of it are visible in the Maps and Layouts nodes of the Catalog pane or view and can be opened independently.

You can run through this tutorial to review the workflow:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/migrate-content-to-arcgis-pro.htm

Answer (score -1):

Here is a[image] screenshot, hope it helps for beginners.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. We're looking for long, useful answers. If the Question is already answered, your Answer should have even more detail, explaining why this is a better solution.